# AttributeError: 'SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: python, file-upload, flask-admin

I am learning flask_admin. I want to add a FileUpload. I can appear the upload file button, however, when I click save button, it will show AttributeError.

```
builtins.AttributeError
AttributeError: 'SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

here is my code:

```
class Movie(db.Model):
    __tablename__="movie"
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True) 
    title=db.Column(db.String(255),unique=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    info=db.Column(db.Text)
    logo=db.Column(db.String(255),unique=True)
    star=db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    playnum=db.Column(db.BigInteger)
    commentnum=db.Column(db.BigInteger)
    area=db.Column(db.String(255))
    release_time=db.Column(db.String(100))
    length=db.Column(db.String(100))
    addtime = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.now) 


class MovieView(ModelView):
    form_overrides = {
        'url': form.FileUploadField
    }

    import os
    import os.path as op
    file_path = op.join(op.dirname(__file__), 'files')

    try:
        os.mkdir(file_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

   form_args = {
       'url': {
           'label': u'movie',
           'base_path': file_path,
           'allow_overwrite': False
       }
    }

admin = Admin(app,name=u'后台管理系统')
admin.add_view(MovieView(Movie, db.session))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pinning `Werkzeug==0.12.2`.

I think we've run into the same issue, though I haven't had time to sort it out far enough to know if it's Python's issue, Werkzeug's issue, or an issue with our environment. I didn't have time to dig very deep; needed to roll back to our old pinned versions and keep moving.

The quick summary of what I found last time I went looking was that Werkzeug semi-recently changed to use SpooledTemporaryFile:

- https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/pull/1198
- https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1210
- https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1220
- https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1222

but SpooledTemporaryFile seems to have some known deficiencies documented on the Python bug tracker

- https://bugs.python.org/issue26175
- https://bugs.python.org/issue32600

and here on SO:

- [Why doesn't tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile implement readable, writable, seekable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160211/why-doesnt-tempfile-spooledtemporaryfile-implement-readable-writable-seekable)

**Update:** 
After seeing that we aren't the only ones running into this, I've decided to go ahead and file an issue with Werkzeug (https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1344)