# Using fastAPI UploadFile with libraries that accept a file-like object

Tags: python, fastapi, temporary-files

I would like to know the best practice for accessing the underlying file object when uploading a file with `fastAPI`.

When uploading a file with fastapi, the object we get is a `starlette.datastructures.UploadFile`.
We can access the underlying `file` attribute which is a `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile`.
We can then access the underlying private `_file` attribute, and pass it to libraries that expect a file-like object.

Below is an example of two routes with `python-docx` and `pdftotext`:

```
@router.post("/open-docx")
async def open_docx(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    mydoc = docx.Document(upload_file.file._file) # 
    # do something

@router.post("/open-pdf")
async def open_pdf(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    mypdf = pdftotext.PDF(upload_file.file._file)
    # do something
```

However, I don't like the idea of accessing the private `_file` attribute. Is there a better way to pass the file object without saving it first?

Note: to reproduce the example above, put the following code in `launch.py` and run `uvicorn launch:app --reload`:

```
import docx
import pdftotext
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile


app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/open-docx")
async def open_docx(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    mydoc = docx.Document(upload_file.file._file)
    # do something
    return {"firstparagraph": mydoc.paragraphs[0].text}

@app.post("/open-pdf")
async def open_pdf(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    mypdf = pdftotext.PDF(upload_file.file._file)
    # do something
    return {"firstpage": mypdf[0]}
```

Comment: `UploadFile.file` is itself file-like object

Comment: I suspect this might be an issue linked with the implementation of SpooledTemporaryFile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160211/why-doesnt-tempfile-spooledtemporaryfile-implement-readable-writable-seekable

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is untested.  Per the docs you can use the `SpooledTemporaryFile` object *without* accessing its underlying wrapper:

> The returned object is a file-like object whose _file attribute is either an io.BytesIO or io.TextIOWrapper object (depending on whether binary or text mode was specified) or a true file object, depending on whether rollover() has been called. *This file-like object* can be used in a with statement, just like a normal file.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile (Emphasis added).

Thus it would seem you can just do:

```py
@router.post("/open-docx")
async def open_docx(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    with upload_file.file as f:
        mydoc = docx.Document(f)
```

Avoid the with if you don't want to close the file.

### Edit: Seekable files

SpooledTemporaryFiles are not properly seekable, sadly.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160211/why-doesnt-tempfile-spooledtemporaryfile-implement-readable-writable-seekable).  It boils down to the fact that they roll over and land on the disk after a certain point, at which point seeking is harder.  Accessing the `_file` attribute is *not* safe because of this rollover.  Thus you either need to save them to disk, or to read them explicitly into a virtual (ram) file.

If you are on Linux, a workaround might be to save the files to `/dev/shm` or `/tmp`, the former of which is in ram, the latter often a ramdisk, and let the OS handle swapping massive files to disk.

Comment: I agree that this should work. Unfortunately,  when I try this solution, I get the following error : AttributeError: 'SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'seekable'.

Comment: @Gabriel See update

Comment: You are right, the behavior is different based on the size of the document. From my experiments, the _file is either a io.BufferedRandom (large doc) or a io.BytesIO (small doc). However, it works in both cases as both of them implement a seekable method.  So on the one hand, you are right, saving the file and reopening it solves the issue but on the other hand, this seems a bit unnecessary as we have access to the io object (even if as you say, it is not safe)

Answer (score 1):

See documentation for UploadFile here:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile

It says it has an attribute named

```
file: A SpooledTemporaryFile (a file-like object). 
This is the actual Python file that you can pass directly to 
other functions or libraries that expect a "file-like" object.
```

So you dont need to access the private ._file attribute.
Just pass the

```
upload_file.file
```

Comment: Somehow I glossed over this even after reading it because the parameter of the function is also called file.